# How do I debug "The action you're trying to perform is causing a fatal error and cannot be performed" errors?

Tags: google-sheets

Since today, I'm no longer able to edit a specific Google Spreadsheet. Every time I try to make an edit, no matter which kind, an error message is displayed:

> The action you're trying to perform is causing a fatal error and cannot be performed.

This happens wether I edit manually, or attempt to modify cells via script. The script will fail with the above message, either when the script ends, or on a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` line.

Only one spreadsheet is affected. I have shared it with another account, but the error occurs on both accounts. There is even a Google Apps Scripts webapp that adds new rows to the sheet, which now also fails.

I did have an *On modification* event handler, which I have now disabled, but the problem persists. And I have not made any changes to any scripts.

*Edit*: A day later, the error message has changed to

> Oops: A server error occurred. The page will reload

I normally use Google Chrome v. 32 on Windows 7/XP, but the problem exists also in Firefox 26 and Internet Explorer 9. I have disabled all browser extensions.

I tried making a copy of the problematic spreadsheet, and the copy works fine. I could have just used the copy, but that is hardly ideal when the URL to the original has been shared with collaborators.

What are my options for debugging this issue?

Comment: Can you share the doc with us?

Comment: Unfortunately not, in this case.

Comment: What browser are you using Vidar and what version?

Comment: I have edited that into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has now been resolved.

Luckily, the spreadsheet in question was owned by a Google Apps for Business account, so I could contact Google Support.

After contacting them and describing the problem, some days later the problem was resolved. I got the following message from Google Support:

> Thanks for your patience as we investigated this issue. There has been
>   a down-push on the current version of spreadsheets that has resolved
>   the issue. Please let me know if you have any further questions.